# Kentico macro to render web.config appsetting

Tags: macros, web-config, kentico, appsettings

I am still pretty green when it comes to Kentico.  I've attempted something like:

{% SettingsHelper.AppSettings["CMSApplicationName"] #%}

But nothing is returned.

I've looked at some of the Kentico 8.2 documentation but the answer eludes me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SettingsHelper is not an available Macro for you to use but an API. The out of box Macro is something like this
{% Settings.Content.PageNotFound.CMSPageNotFoundUrl #%} or {% Settings.GetValue("CMSPageNotFoundUrl", "") #%}
which you can get Settings value from the Settings application.

If you want to get the AppSettings value in the web.config but use Macro, you will need to write a custom macro [Create custom macro](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Registering+custom+macro+methods)
pass in the keyname into the method, and use the API you have to return the value.